# How to upload image using volley with header token android

Tags: android, android-volley

I have an image and I want to upload this image to my web service using Volley library, the problem is I'm looking for a how to do it but still haven't found.
I am trying to upload image with Volley Multipart Request but I am not get success response from server but when I upload image using postman it's return success. [This is my postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8elV.jpg).

I search relate this but not get any idea.

below is my code

```
private void uploadMedia(final String token) {
    VolleyMultipartRequest volleyMultipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, upload_image,
            new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

                    //  iv_imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    Log.e("VolleyOnResponse200", response.toString());

                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
                        Log.e("response",obj+"");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VolleyonErrorResponse200", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    // Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                    if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null) {
                        try {
                            String res = new String(response.data,
                                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
                            // Now you can use any deserializer to make sense of data
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                            // Couldn't properly decode data to string
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JSONException e2) {
                            // returned data is not JSONObject?
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            params.put("Authorization", "bearer  " + token);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
            long imagename = System.currentTimeMillis();
            params.put("image", new DataPart(imagename + ".jpg", getFileDataFromDrawable(bitmap)));
            return params;
        }
    };
    volleyMultipartRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            999999999,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    //adding the request to volley
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(volleyMultipartRequest);

}
public byte[] getFileDataFromDrawable(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

This is my VolleyMultipartRequest class

```
public class VolleyMultipartRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {

private final String twoHyphens = "--";
private final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
private final String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();

private Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
private Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
private Map<String, String> mHeaders;


public VolleyMultipartRequest(int method, String url,
                              Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener,
                              Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.mListener = listener;
    this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

    try {
        // populate text payload
        Map<String, String> params = getParams();
        if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
            textParse(dos, params, getParamsEncoding());
        }

        // populate data byte payload
        Map<String, DataPart> data = getByteData();
        if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {
            dataParse(dos, data);
        }

        // close multipart form data after text and file data
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        return bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Custom method handle data payload.
 *
 * @return Map data part label with data byte
 * @throws AuthFailureError
 */
protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() throws AuthFailureError {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        return Response.success(
                response,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
    mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
}

/**
 * Parse string map into data output stream by key and value.
 *
 * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
 * @param params           string inputs collection
 * @param encoding         encode the inputs, default UTF-8
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void textParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, String> params, String encoding) throws IOException {
    try {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            buildTextPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + encoding, uee);
    }
}

/**
 * Parse data into data output stream.
 *
 * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle file attachment
 * @param data             loop through data
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void dataParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, DataPart> data) throws IOException {
    for (Map.Entry<String, DataPart> entry : data.entrySet()) {
        buildDataPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
    }
}

/**
 * Write string data into header and data output stream.
 *
 * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
 * @param parameterName    name of input
 * @param parameterValue   value of input
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
}

/**
 * Write data file into header and data output stream.
 *
 * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle data parsing
 * @param dataFile         data byte as DataPart from collection
 * @param inputName        name of data input
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void buildDataPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, DataPart dataFile, String inputName) throws IOException {
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
            inputName + "\"; filename=\"" + dataFile.getFileName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
    if (dataFile.getType() != null && !dataFile.getType().trim().isEmpty()) {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + dataFile.getType() + lineEnd);
    }
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile.getContent());
    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

    int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
}

public class DataPart {
    private String fileName;
    private byte[] content;
    private String type;

    public DataPart(String selectedPath, String path) {
    }

    public DataPart(String name, byte[] data) {
        fileName = name;
        content = data;
    }

    String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    byte[] getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    String getType() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: convert bitmap to base64 and post

Comment: but we need without base64, as a file

Comment: Finally I got my mistake, thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see below code I think there is problem

```
 @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        params.put("Authorization", "bearer  " + token);
        return params;
    }
```

please comment below line

```
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

This will help you